# How do I read n rows from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read the subset of some data from a large CSV file, I have tried using nrows, but it returns the following error message, 'TypeError: 'nrows' is an invalid keyword argument for this function' unsure how to correct it.

```
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = reader(csv_file, nrows=350)
    lines = list(csv_reader)
    print(lines) 

#Aim was to print 350 rows in a list of lists

TypeError: 'nrows' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to read only 350 lines from the `csv_reader`:

```py
from csv import reader
from itertools import islice

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = reader(csv_file)
    lines = list(islice(csv_reader, 0, 350))
    print(lines)
```